# Is the limit on the number of databases in an Azure SQL managed instance a hard limit?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I see the documentation for Azure SQL Managed Instance lists a limit of 100 databases per managed instance.   I would like to understand if this is a soft limit that is adjustable on request or a hard limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard limit that cannot be changed at this time.

The limit is imposed to ensure seamless operation of the instance and its performance.